# How to place images directly on object

Tags: materials, image

I'm currently learning Blender,exploring Skyrim 3D objects and wondering whether I can place my images directly on an object.

Or in other words, is it possible to add like a picture of a star, or coke bottle directly on an object (like a cube) and have it draw it's self on the object? ATM the only way i know how to edit the textures is directly with the draw tool.

I'm sorry if i'm not being clear enough, i'm still very new to blender.

Comment: New to blender? start here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/blender_render/materials/index.htm

Comment: With just a bit more specificity than @cegaton, in the "resources for Blender page", I'd specifically recommend the "on line course" category.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorials! I couldn't find a good one anywhere.

Comment: One of the problems with lots of types of software, is not knowing what to call something. I would expect that searching for tutorials using "photograph' as one of the search parameters will result in slim pickings. ON the other hand, if you search for image textures, you may be overwhelmed with the search results. But this is not just a "Blender problem"; I spend more time trying to figure out what keywords to use when looking for help with my spreadsheet and word processing software than actually finding the answers I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question asd71, is "sort of". You can place your 2D images directly on an object through the process of assigning image textures to materials, and assigning the materials to objects. And in one special case, one can assign an image to an object, specifically a plane object, and have the picture appear, something as a photograph of a painting.

However, it is not presently possible to assign an image like a star or a Coke® to a Blender object primitive and have the object be modified to the shape of the star or Coke® bottle. You must first create the mesh for the desired object, and then you can apply materials and textures to it.

Comment: Darn, i was hoping for a photoshop like image placement. Anyways, I've figured it out thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is commonly called decals in computer graphics.

In a game, if you shoot a wall and see bullet marks, it is a decal. I think they often are planes with a translucent texture hovering a tiny distance above the real surface.

The same thing is quite easy to make in blender.

Of course, since blender is not a computer game, there are other methods as well. For instance, add a second UV map to the object and add the texture to the material with that map.